# Use 'sed' to find a number in line

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am trying to use unix sed command to find line numbers that match a particular regular expression. The pattern of my file is below

```
Murali : 20 #
Krishna: 21 $
Hari: 22 @
Murali : 23 #
```

I need to output only the numbers like below using `SED` command

```
20
21
22
23
```

Can you please help me with the regular expression for `SED`.

Comment: Why not use cut? like `cut -d' ' -f2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$ cat input
Murali : 20 #
Krishna: 21 $
Hari: 22 @
Murali : 23 #

$ sed -r 's/^[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*/\1/g' input
20
21
22
23
```

- `[^0-9]+` matches anything other than digit
- `([0-9]+)` matches digits, captured in group 1
- `.*` matches the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer the `awk` version

```
awk -F":" '{print $2--}'
```

**Output :**

```
20
21
22
23
```

Comment: Even some shorter `awk -F: '{$0=+$2}1'` or `awk -F: '{print +$2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`.  It may be simpler to understand than a regex `sed` solution,

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file
20
21
22
23
```

Print second last field.